# Thread in RUNNABLE state in weblogic

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic

I am getting the below error in Weblogic logs

```
    "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '49' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000116cc8800 nid=0x528 runnable [0xffffffff6284d000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop(US_ASCII.java:83)
            at sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII$Decoder.decodeLoop(US_ASCII.java:127)
            at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:561)
            at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:317)
            at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
            - locked <0x0000000680308e00> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
            at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
            at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
            at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
            - locked <0x0000000680308e00> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
            at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
 at com.infosys.ci.fioutbound.custom.SmsSenderDrc.sendSms(SmsSenderDrc.java:236)
    at com.infosys.ci.fioutbound.custom.SmsSenderDrc.executeOutboundRequest(SmsSenderDrc.java:70)
    at com.infosys.ci.fiusb.app.AbstractOutboundServiceProvider.executeService(Unknown Source)
    at com.infosys.ci.fiusb.app.FIUsbServiceExecutor.executeService(Unknown Source)
    at com.infosys.ci.fiusb.app.FIUsbMessageExecutor.executeService(FIUsbMessageExecutor.java:726)
    at com.infosys.ci.fiusb.app.FIUsbMessageExecutor.executeMessage(FIUsbMessageExecutor.java:415)
```

The error is from a jar file(SmsSenderDrc.sendSms) which makes a SOAP API request to a third party system. This jar file is called from my application every 1 minute. The code in the jar is as follows -
     public String sendSms(String reqXml, String messangerEngine)

```
  {
    String smsService = messangerEngine;

String outputString = "";
String responseString = "";
try
{
  String soapAction = "http://www.pces.mk/WCF/SMPP34/ISMSChannelAPIService/SendSMS";
  URL smsServiceUrl = new URL(smsService);
  URLConnection conn = smsServiceUrl.openConnection();
  HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
  ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[reqXml.length()];
  buffer = reqXml.getBytes();
  bout.write(buffer);
  byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();
  httpconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
    String.valueOf(b.length));
  httpconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
    "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
  httpconn.setRequestProperty(smsService, smsService);
  httpconn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);
  httpconn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  httpconn.setDoOutput(true);
  httpconn.setDoOutput(true);
  OutputStream out = httpconn.getOutputStream();
  out.write(b);
  conn.setConnectTimeout(120000);
  conn.setReadTimeout(120000);
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
    httpconn.getInputStream());

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
  while ((responseString = in.readLine()) != null) {   //line number 236
    outputString = outputString + responseString;
  }
  isr.close();
}
catch (MalformedURLException ex)
{
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
return outputString;
```

}

Is this an error message which can affect the performance of application ? Do I need to modify anything in the code ?

Comment: The snippet you provided is a Thread Dump and not application / server logs. Question here is why thread dump is printed in logs. Did you generate it or it was in logs?

Comment: It was in logs.

Comment: Until and unless you are seeing some major issue with the application there is no harm as seen in thread dump... The thread is in runnable state and not stuck.

Comment: I have the same understanding, but still worried as it comes in our Production environment

Comment: Can you go through your server logs to see why Thread Dumps are written in first place? 
Enabling Diagnostic Module can be one of the reason.